# Member in Hazelcast Map in removed when adding new cluster node

Tags: hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast version 3.9.1 and when tried to add a new node many map Members are removed.
We are using  Discovering Members by TCP and adding all IP's in the new node and then restart Hazelcast service.
What is a reason of removing map member?

Answer (score 0):

In a running cluster, Map data is not removed but repartitioned i.e. data is rebalanced across the cluster. In other words, when a new member is added to the cluster, some of the existing entries move to the new member.

If you only wanted to add members to an existing cluster then there is no need to restart, Hazelcast automatically rebalances the data.

If there are no backups enabled and you restart the cluster, then the data is lost as data is stored in memory. To prevent data loss, enabled backup (default is 1 synchronous backup enabled) and do not shut down the entire cluster at once.

Answer (score 0):

As wildnez said in his response, adding a new node will cause rebalancing to happen; so while map entries may be removed from the map of a particular node, they will remain in the cluster.

As a concrete example, if you are using the default of 1 backup, and start up a cluster with one node and 1000 entries, then all 1000 entries will be in the map of that node.   There will be no backups in that case because even though you specified 1 backup, backups won't be stored on the same node as their primary.

If you add a second node, then approximately 50% of the map entries will be migrated to the new node.   For the entries that migrate, their backups will be added on the first node, and for the map entries that don't migrate, their backups will be created on the second node.

If you add a third node, migration will happen again, and each node will have roughly one third of the primary entries and one third of the backups.

Adding a node should never cause map entries to be removed from the cluster, but they will cause migration of entries between cluster members.